# Azure Machine Learning Studio registered model save directory

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

When I register a model to azure machine learning studio where is it saved on?

Answer (score 0):

The registered models are stored in the storage account associated to the Azure Machine Learning workspace. You can see where it is stored from the Azure Machine Learning Studio (web UI) inside **notebooks / <your_username> / azureml-models / <your_modelname> / <your_modelversion>**.

Alternatively, you can access the storage account directly via Azure Portal or Azure Storage Explorer and look for the **File Shares > code* > <your_username> / azureml-models / <your_modelname> / <your_modelversion>**.

The last option would be using the Azure Machine Learning SDK to discover the relative path:

```
from azureml.core import Workspace, Model
ws = Workspace.from_config()
print(Model.get_model_path(model_name = 'RegressionDecisionTree', version = 1, _workspace= ws))
```